# LongListSelector does not exists in the namespace clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit

I'm trying to use the longlistselector from Windows Toolkit in my project but I always have this error.
I added the namespace to my xaml and try to restrart visual studio several times.
Of course, the toolkit is installed with nuget package manager.

EDIT : I'm on windows phone 8.1

Here is the XAML code:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Background="#00000000">
        <Pivot Margin="0,81,0,0" Title="">
            <PivotItem Header="Vidéos" Margin="19,0,19,-0.333">
                <Grid Background="#00000000">
                    <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="VideosList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="406" Margin="-1,43,0,-103" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="363" ItemsSource="{Binding Videos}" SelectionChanged="PlayVideo" SelectionMode="Single" IsItemClickEnabled="False" Background="#00000000">
                    </phone:LongListSelector>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Output" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,315" FontSize="36"/>
                    <Button Content="Clear Files" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,415,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="352" Click="Delete_File"/>
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Recherche" Foreground="White">
                <Grid>
                    <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="63" Width="33" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Parcourir" Margin="0,18,130,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
        <TextBlock Height="92" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Text="EPIVIDEO" FontSize="32" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Digital Desolation" Foreground="#FF00E8FF"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Can anyone help me please ? I don't know what to do?

Comment: I implemented the LongListSelector for WP8.1 WinRT because it is missing there, see http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LongListSelector

Comment: Thank you for your link but the answer that saravanan posted is better for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LongListSelector is not available for Windows phone 8.1,You can use SemanticZoom.

Reference: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/08/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-what-controls-are-new.aspx?

Comment: I got the same error. Maybe I added the wrong namespace. I don't know.

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't know that this control replaced the longlistselector !